# Reshaping pandas dataframe from categorical to counts

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to reshape a dataframe with two columns: ID and categorical, so that there is a column for each unique categorical value.

Here is what I have:

```
   ID Animal
    foo cat
    foo dog
    bar cat
    baz cat
    biz dog
    biz cow
    biz dog
```

And here is what I would like:

```
ID  cat dog cow
foo 1   1   0
bar 1   0   0
baz 1   0   0
biz 0   1   2
```

I tried:

```
df.groupby(by='ID').count()
```

which gives:

```
Index Animal
foo 2
bar 1
baz 1
biz 3
```

I also tried:

```
df.pivot_table(values='Animal')
df.stack(level='Animal')
```

the former throws DataError: no numeric types to aggregate, the later throws KeyError: Level Animal must be same as name (None)

Comment: Here's how it would work with groupby: `df.groupby(['ID', 'Animal']).size().unstack('Animal', fill_value=0)` Use crosstab though - it is faster and more idiomatic.

Comment: @ayhan, please turn your comment into answer for the sake of completenes

Comment: @MaxU I think we need a canonical question not to list these possibilities every time :) This tag needs a little clean up so I refrain from answering.

Comment: @ayhan, that's true. But usually it's much easier to answer again instead of searching for a proper question/answer... ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we can use [crosstab()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) method:

```
In [17]: pd.crosstab(df.ID, df.Animal).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
Out[17]:
     cat  cow  dog
ID
bar    1    0    0
baz    1    0    0
biz    0    1    2
foo    1    0    1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `.str.get_dummies`, `sum` with `level=0` or `groupby` with `sum`:

## Option 1

```
df.set_index('ID')['Animal'].str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
```

OR

## Option 2

```
df.set_index('ID')['Animal'].str.get_dummies().groupby('ID').sum()
```

Output:

```
     cat  cow  dog
ID                
bar    1    0    0
baz    1    0    0
biz    0    1    2
foo    1    0    1
```

## Option 3

```
df.set_index(['ID','Animal'],append=True).assign(count=1)['count'].unstack(fill_value=0).sum(level=1)

Animal  cat  cow  dog
ID                   
bar       1    0    0
baz       1    0    0
biz       0    1    2
foo       1    0    1
```

Using pivot_table and assign:

## Option 4

```
 pd.pivot_table(df.assign(count=1),values='count',index='ID',columns='Animal',aggfunc='sum',fill_value=0)

Animal  cat  cow  dog
ID                   
bar       1    0    0
baz       1    0    0
biz       0    1    2
foo       1    0    1
```

Comment: Ahhh heck, just use @MaxU's solution. ;-)