# Rename Pandas index in function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
nationwide_measures = pd.read_sql_query("""select state,
          measure_id,
          measure_name,
          score
from timely_and_effective_care___hospital;""", conn)
```

And I have created the function:

```
# Function to grab measure values
def get_stats(group):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Minimum': group.min(), 'Maximum': group.max(), 'Average': group.mean(), 'Standard Deviation': group.std()}, index = [0])
    return df

# Function output
nationwide_measure_results = nationwide_measures1['score'].groupby(nationwide_measures1['measure_id']).apply(get_stats).unstack()
```

The output is a dataframe with the following 5 columns:

> "Index" | ('Average',0) | ('Maximum',0) | ('Minimum',0)| ('Standard
>   Deviation',0)

How can I change the output to get 6 columns renamed:

> "Measure ID" | "Measure Name" | "Average" | "Maximum" | "Minimum" | "Standard
>   Deviation"

I have tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Minimum': group.min(), 'Maximum': group.max(), 'Average': group.mean(), 'Standard Deviation': group.std()}, index = [0], columns=["Measure ID", "Average", "Maximum", "Minimum", "Standard Deviation"])
```

AND

```
df.columns = ["Measure ID", "Average", "Maximum", "Minimum", "Standard Deviation"]
```

Inside the function, neither works.

Comment: Is your column index a MultiIndex.  What is the output of `df.columns`?

Comment: MultiIndex(levels=[['Average', 'Maximum', 'Minimum', 'Standard Deviation'], [0]],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0]])

Comment: so you want your index values to be turned into a column of your dataframe? and have it called Measure ID

Comment: Yes @jacoblaw this is correct. I also need to add the "Measure Name" field from the original query.

Comment: If you can provide an example, that will be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'state':np.random.choice(['TX','CA','NY'],100),'measure_id':np.random.randint(1,5,100),'measure_name':np.nan,'score':np.random.randint(50,100,100)})

dict = {1:'Measure A',2:'Measure B',3:'Measure C',4:'Measure D',5:'Measure E'}

df['measure_name'] = df['measure_id'].map(dict)
```

Input Data:

```
   measure_id measure_name  score state
0           3    Measure C     82    CA
1           3    Measure C     93    CA
2           4    Measure D     69    NY
3           1    Measure A     56    NY
4           4    Measure D     66    CA

df_out=(df.groupby(['measure_id','measure_name'])['score'].agg(['mean','max','min','std'])
         .rename(columns={'mean':'Average','max':'Maximum','min':'Minimum','std':'Standard Deviation'})
         .rename_axis(['Measure ID','Measure Name'])
         .reset_index())

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   Measure ID Measure Name    Average  Maximum  Minimum  Standard Deviation
0           1    Measure A  74.346154       99       53           13.734460
1           2    Measure B  70.720000       97       50           16.084465
2           3    Measure C  76.130435       97       51           14.943239
3           4    Measure D  77.576923       97       56           10.756107
```

Comment: What about the part about actually naming the columns? Please see my updated question, one of the columns from the query is missing and I need to add that back in also.

Comment: This tough with your you actually posting a head of the dataframe.  Let's look at some other SO on pandas and see how most people put a samle of the input dataframe and expected outputs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150451/reshaping-pandas-dataframe-from-categorical-to-counts this is a pretty good example of a good question with inputs and expected outputs.  This will help you get better help with your Pandas questions.

Comment: Sorry, I dont know how to add in the output tables properly- I tried :(

Comment: "AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'swaplevel'"

Comment: @zsad512  See my example.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! The only question I have is how can I rename "measure_id" and "measure_name" TO "Measure ID" and "Measure Name"?

Comment: We need to use rename_axis(['Measure ID','Measure Name']) before the reset_index().   See edit

Answer (score 0):

First, here's a way to add new columns to the dataframe.

```
df['Measure ID'] = pd.Series(df.index.values)
```

**example**

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Minimum': [1,1], 'Maximum': [0,0], 'Average': [0,1], 'Standard Deviation': [1,324]}, index = [0,1], columns=["Average", "Maximum", "Minimum", "Standard Deviation"])
       Average  Maximum  Minimum  Standard Deviation
0        0        0        1                   1
1        1        0        1                 324
>>> df['Measure ID'] = pd.Series(df.index.values)
       Average  Maximum  Minimum  Standard Deviation  Measure ID
0        0        0        1                   1           0
1        1        0        1                 324           1
```

It's hard to give you *exactly* what you need, since we don't have all the input needed. But you can follow the same format for adding new columns

```
df['NEW COLUMN NAME'] = pd.Series(NEW_COLUMN_DATA)
```

I'm assuming you'll want the columns ordered in the same way as your example, here's how to re-order columns.

Let's say this is you dataframe:

```
   Average  Maximum  Minimum  Standard Deviation  Measure ID Measure Name
0        0        0        1                   1           0        Place
1        1        0        1                 324           1       Holder
```

then we can do this:

```
>>> cols = df.columns.tolist()
['Average',
 'Maximum',
 'Minimum',
 'Standard Deviation',
 'Measure ID',
 'Measure Name']
>>> cols = cols[-2:] + cols[:-2]
['Measure ID',
 'Measure Name',
 'Average',
 'Maximum',
 'Minimum',
 'Standard Deviation']
>>> df = df[cols]
   Measure ID Measure Name  Average  Maximum  Minimum  Standard Deviation
0           0        Place        0        0        1                   1
1           1       Holder        1        0        1                 324
```

Comment: No, this just adds a column to the output labeled " ('Measure ID', 0) " that is full of 0's. The CURRENT INDEX values are the "measure_id" values from the dataframe....that is fine....I just need to replace the column header "index" with the label "measure_id".....Im beginning to wonder if this is even possible. Moreover, I have lost the column "measure_name" from the original query and I need to get that back

Comment: @zsad512 why are you trying to add a label over the indexes?